# How to join lines without adding space for empty line in Vim

Tags: vim, spacing

When I use `J` to join lines spaces are automatically added as expected. However when I have a line with words followed by a blank line and I want to remove that blank line with `J` it adds a space to my current line. I considered `nnoremaping` `J` to `Jx` so that the white space is removed, but that would make it not add spaces when I am joining two lines with text in them. After looking through the manual I could not find anything that sounded like what I want.

Below are some examples of what I am looking to happen. and I am sorry in advance for the formatting.

Currently I have:

Before (spaces are replaced with `-` for readability):

```
Some-text
```

After:

```
Some-text-
```

Before:

```
Some-text
Some-more
```

After:

```
Some-text-Some-more
```

I desire:

Before (spaces are replaced with `-` for redability):

```
Some-text
```

After:

```
Some-text
```

Before:

```
Some-text
Some-more
```

After:

```
Some-text-Some-more
```

In short, I want a space when lines contain characters are joined and no space added when the line being joined is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a function to toggle between `gJ` and `J` if the next line is empty. Then map that function to `J`:

```
noremap J :call J()<cr>
function! J()
    if getline(line('.')+1)=="" | exe 'normal gJ' | else | join | endif
endfunction
```

`getline(line('.')+1)==""` checks if the next line is empty.

Comment: Thank you this is just what I wanted and I am going to accept it, but it is a shame that there is no option to enable this without making a function. Thanks!